# Javascript and Ajax display image

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use ajax to load data and am trying to display the image using javascript. However the image is not displaying, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I need a hand

```js
URL="testurl";
function getdata() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let image = document.getElementById("image");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
             var img = data.image;
              image.innerHTML += '<img src="' + img + '">';


}

    xhr.open('GET', URL);
    xhr.send();
}
```

From the console.log(data.image);
it shows the image was loaded but it just won't display on

```js
image.innerHTML += '<img src="' + img + '">';
```

Comment: That suggests that URL you are using is wrong. Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to debug it.

Comment: Image (`<img />`) doesn't have `.innerHTML`. It has `.src`. And there is no need to load anything to set that `.src`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("image");` is what element? What is `img` exactly?

Answer (score -1):

```
image.src = data.image;
```

You don't set an image's source url by using the `.innerHTML` property. Use `.src`

To address the silly remarks, if `image` is *not* referring to an `<img>` tag, you should probably rework the html so that it is. There's no real reason to be adding innerHTML that needs to be parsed when you can just directly manipulate properties in DOM objects. Happy coding!

Comment: You're assuming that `image` is an `<img>` element and not, for example, a `<div>`.

Comment: it is possible only if it is a image tag but here ,from the context it doesnt look like image tage

Comment: The json data look like {"image":"image.png"}  . when add the line, i add image=data.image, the image still doesn't display. Also when i create an image element  var image = document.createElement("img"); image.src=data.image; and then try to image.appendChild(image). it still doesn't display any image.